# Невозможно подключиться к серверу - FileZilla

Tags: php, сервер, клиент-сервер, ftp, filezilla

друзья.
При подключении по FTP возникла ошибка :

"Статус:    Не удалось установить соединение с "ECONNREFUSED - Соединение отклонено сервером".
Ошибка: Невозможно подключиться к серверу
Статус: Ожидание повтора..."

Причем первый раз подключится удалось, но потом соединение прервалось и теперь не удается подключиться.

Все данные многократно проверил всё верно, пробовал активное\пассивное подключение, антивируса нет, брандмауэр выключен, пробовал ещё через тотал командер и WinScp так же не удается подключиться.

В чем может быть проблема? Очень буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: ip на серере заблочен, например.

Comment: Именно мой ip? Как это обойти, впн поможет?

Comment: добавить ip  в белый список.